# How to switch from default H2 DB of jBPM to another Database like MariaDB?

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, mariadb, jbpm

I've installed MariaDB connector in jBPM 7.53 Final with .jar file and configured MariaDB database locally. Checked in management console and saw that datasources and JDBC connectors look good (MariaDBDS is enabled), but an error showing in runtime "Boot errors occurred during the start of server".

> Failure description: {"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not
> installed:" =>
> ["jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_7_1_jar"],"WFLYCTL0180:
> Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" =>
> ["jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/MariaDBDS is missing
> [jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_7_1_jar]","org.wildfly.data-source.MariaDBDS
> is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_7_1_jar]"]}
>
> Missing dependencies: jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/MariaDBDS is
> missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_7_1_jar]
> org.wildfly.data-source.MariaDBDS is missing
> [jboss.jdbc-driver.mariadb-java-client-2_7_1_jar]

I have configured MariaDB Java connector in the jBPM standalone.xml

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/MariaDBDS" pool-name="MariaDBDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/mysql</connection-url>
            <driver-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            <driver>mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>root</user-name>
                <password>admin</password>
            </security>
            <validation>
                <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
            </validation>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="mariadb" module="org.mariadb">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

and I have copied the MariaDB Java connector to JBPM_HOME/modules/com/mariadb/main/mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar and configured the module.xml like this:

```xml
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.mariadb">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Also, in Business-Central to new process instance appeared this attention:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6B9Q.png)

What I am missing or change in these steps? Any idea if jBPM works with the external DB or not?

Comment: The error doesn't seem to have anything to do with jBPM itself, but that JBoss can't the right module, which suggests a configuration error.

Answer (score 1):

@KrenarR have you set up these properties under system-properties as well?

```
<property name="org.kie.server.persistence.ds" value="java:jboss/MariaDBDS"/>
<property name="org.kie.server.persistence.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
```

You can also add the driver as a core module by means of jboss_cli:

```
module add --name=org.mariadb --resources=mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

Also check this line in the datasource:

```
<driver>mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar</driver>
```

I think it should be just the driver name you have defined:

```
<driver>mariadb</driver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the documentation [Switch to another database](https://jbpm.org/learn/gettingStarted.html)
 from jbpm.org for detailed steps.